# Firebase as backend for mobile app, that has multiple admins/multisite

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

The problem is the following.

Client wants an app, that can be sold to different users via Play Store and AppStore. This app has to have a backend server, but users should be able to see only the data that belongs to their user. This is so far a simple authentication/permission problem, but it gets trickier.

If we had a single backend with User Accounts with permission to manage only data that belongs to them, then whoever sells the app will have to pay for the Firebase account for customers traffic usage too.

So the client wants to sell a pair of app + backend, where backends monthly fees are paid by the customer.
Is there a way to configure something like that in Firebase, and make it easy and friendly enough for the customers to set up their account from the app on first startup?

Comment: I think Amazon has that sort of customizations for billing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This format unmanaged user seperator. Firebase has simple authentication. Is is not useful for multicompany. Seperate database or develop custom backend.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a fairly standard white-labelled app. I recommend keeping each of the re-sold apps in a separate project, which makes it trivial to then charge each buyer separately for their usage.